# How can i write query to calc percent of the difference two field?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in `sql server`,have this table on `sql` server:

```
Telno       nchar(20)
CurBill     float
Cycle       nchar(8)
```

and into that table has this data:

```
Telno       CurBill     Cycle           
 123         2000        951
 123         2500        952
```

write this query for calculate difference two number:

```
SELECT  y.Telno,
        t.Cycle+'-'+y.Cycle Cycle,
        y.CurBill - t.CurBill Price
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills] y
INNER JOIN [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills] t
    ON y.Telno = t.TelNo AND CAST(y.Cycle as int)-1 = CAST(t.Cycle as int)
```

that query minus two `CurBill` per `Cycle` and show me this:

```
123 951-952     1000 ----->calc this formull(CurBill(952)-CurBill(951))
```

now want to show percent of decrease or increase of `CurBill` minus,for example show me this:

```
123      951-952       150%--->calc formulla(CurBill(951)-CurBill(952))/CurBill(951) *100
```

and other example imagine `GetOnlineBills` data is this:

```
Telno       CurBill     Cycle           
 123         2500        951    
 123         2000        952
```

and show me this:

```
123      951-952       -150%--->calc formulla(CurBill(951)-CurBill(952))/CurBill(951) *100
```

How can i implant that?thanks.

Comment: Can you show expected result for one table and also tag version of SQLServer you are using

Comment: I'm asuming there could be more cycles and you what to work with the last two cycles for each telno, right?

Comment: @TheGameiswar I'm using sql server 2014

Comment: @Horaciux have more than 1 million record and just show me two record want to calculate for all of record

Comment: please add two more cycles data and add expected output

Comment: It was 2000 and then 2500 it is 125% not 150%? Am I right? And what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @TheGameiswar my friend that query (minus query in question) calc all cycle and not important how cycle in table.

Comment: ((2000-2500)/2000)*100 =-25% @gofr1

Comment: Why not just add this formulas to your query?

Comment: Your life would be a lot easier if you used proper datatypes. Converting a column to int is a pretty good indication it shouldn't be varchar. And you are also using floats which is an approximate datatype. If you want accurate and consistent results you should use an exact datatype like numeric.

Comment: @gofr1 how can i write that on my query?